# Unable to find Visual Studio Code's VSCode downloaded from Ubunto Software

Tags: launchpad-api

I have tried to find it using Terminal and also installing it using the sudo apt install command with the downloaded file name. Terminal returned 'unsupported file'

Checked Ubuntu Software, which has the product marked Installed.

Q. Where is it. how do I find it.

Previous actions:

- Installed node js
- Installed java openjdk version "11.0.10"

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1315247/edit) to tell us the downloaded file name and the package name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all concerned. I found a solution.

1. Removed original download from Ubuntu Software
2. Found deb download link from Visual Studio Code website
3. Saved package to Downloads
4. Clicked to open and selected Install
5. Upon completion, checked version with Terminal Command "code -V" which returned a string commencing 1.53.1

Again thank you. I am new to Linux and to creating my own workstation, as I have always had a DBA to do it for me, so it as been a fun few days and I am almost there now. Just a couple of VSCode extensions to do and I am working again.